# Need help coming up with a query

Tags: sql, database

For every name in my table I would like to sum up the quantity that appears beside each name for each name.

The column names are au_fname, au_lname, and qty

Here is what the table looks like

```
Johnson         White           5               
Marjorie        Green           5               
Cheryl          Carson          5               
Michael         O'Leary         5               
Dean            Straight        5               
Meander         Smith           5               
Abraham         Bennet          5               
Ann             Dull            5               
Burt            Gringlesby      5               
Charlene        Locksley        5               
Morningstar     Greene          5               
Reginald        Blotchet-Halls  5               
Akiko           Yokomoto        5               
Innes           del Castillo    5               
Michel          DeFrance        5               
Dirk            Stringer        5               
Stearns         MacFeather      5               
Livia           Karsen          5               
Sylvia          Panteley        5               
Sheryl          Hunter          5
```

Some names repeat multiple times.

Comment: $1,000,000 question: have you tried writing it on your own?

Comment: yea but I need help coming up with some logic I only wrote the Select part though

Comment: Aren't the names all the same?  In which case the answer is 5.

Comment: No I want the sum for each name, theirs more in the table and they are not always the same

Comment: You have 2 name (fname, lname) columns ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need to group by au_fname and au_lname, then use the SUM(qty) aggregate to get your answer.  Below is how you would do it.

```
SELECT
  au_fname, 
  au_lname
  SUM(qty)
FROM yourTableName
GROUP BY
  au_fname, 
  au_lname
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a `personID` in case there are two people named John Smith?

If not, you can use

```
Select au_fname, au_lname, sum(qty) as sum_qty
from table
group by au_fname, au_lname
```

---

really too bad there isn't a personID, but you use what you have.

A little nicer would be:

```
Select au_lname + ', ' + au_fname
```

Comment: Its assumed that if the names are repeated then they are the same person.